# Trouble with asp.net MVC web application downloading to browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, tinymce

I have a web app, which has developed a bit of a lag in opening up a screen.

I turned on Chrome's developer tools, and the screenshot below is from that.

Can anyone tell me please, the long delay in the timeline, from almost 0 to 10s - is that caused by the jquery.validate.unob.... or is it the theme.js file from tinymce that is taking 10 seconds?

Is anyone aware of the TinyMCE files taking so long elsewhere?

[image: screenshot from developer tools]

Comment: How are you loading those files on the page? Just from a script tag, or are you using some sort of asynchronous loader?

Comment: Hi - it's a published asp.net mvc web site.  So it's however that has configured it.  When I published it, I selected "release" rather than debug.  Thanks a lot, Mark

Comment: Have you verified that it's not just a network issue for you? Have you been getting complaints from users, or is it just something you noticed? Are you able to access the site from another location, like home, a coffee shop, etc?

Comment: If you are able to access it from another location, do so and see if you get the same delay

Comment: Hi - yes, it was a user in Canada that noticed it.  I put it down to the server being in the UK, and him being in Canada.  However, I'm in the UK, and get the exact same delay.  I just don't know if it's the theme.js that's taking ages, or the jquery one - the Size/Content column says "from cache" - but I can't explain the delay.  The raw theme.js file is 800kb+.  Thanks, Mark